# HTML5 Video not play in localhost, but it can play using "Open with Live Server" in vs code

Tags: html, css, video

```
<video id="videoSL" muted autoplay loop="" class="video" controls>
    <source src="/Development2.0/media.io_Fergus BluePrint Loyalty Program Video.webm"
    type="video/webm"/>
</video>
```

When I viewed the webpage using http://localhost:12000/home, the video does not show up, I can only see a video controls.

But when I use open with liver server in vs code, I can see the video playing.

However, if I use open in default browser, I can only see a video controls again

[The video control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaHgd.png)

Comment: What do you mean by "video frame". Could you provide a picture?

Comment: Hi, it is acutally the control of video tag. I have add the picture at the bottom

Comment: Okay, i guess the path of your video is incorrect when you connecting on http://localhost:12000/home.

Comment: It shoud not be. Since I can view the video if I use open with live server  in vs code. So the path should be correct

Comment: What is the Live server URL? Do you use an absolute or relative path to the video?

Comment: Also, change your video name so it does not contain any spaces.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1:5500/Development2.0/bluethumb/views/partials/media.html

This is the live server URL, the video works in this URL.

But. when it comes to http://localhost:12000/home, the video does not work

Comment: Try using an [absolute path](https://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001708.htm) to link your video.

Comment: I change it  to absolute path, it does not fix the prolem. In addition, the live server URL  does not work now. Also the remove space does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be that this file (`/Development2.0/media.io_Fergus BluePrint Loyalty Program Video.webm`) is not stored on the local host and the link is defaulting to `localhost:12000/Development2.0/media.io_Fergus BluePrint Loyalty Program Video.webm`, where it is not stored.

Try moving your file into your localhost and see if that works. You can test if it is on the localhost by going to `localhost:12000/Development2.0/media.io_Fergus BluePrint Loyalty Program Video.webm`.

If that doesn't work, try replacing the `space`s with `%20`s. Edit: Do this in the `<source>` tag.

Comment: Yes, I did not upload the file  into localhost.

Comment: I search. the internet. Do I neet to use node js code or php code to upload the file. to localhost?

Comment: I don't really know, because I don't use localhost. This Medium article can explain it. https://medium.com/quick-code/uploading-files-and-serve-directory-listing-using-nodejs-6f353f65be5